# Java Casting Object into Object[] Array And Enriched For Loop

Tags: java, arrays, object, foreach, arguments

Lets say I pass my arguments into my function like this.

Seems the Object outside arguments knows it's a `Object[]` array.
But the `Object[]` inside it are not Object Array's but plain Object's

```
Object[] arguments = {
    new Object[] {"command", "value"},  
    new Object[] {"List_test", Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4")},
    new Object[] {"single command"}
};
myFunc(arguments);
```

```
public void myFunc(Object[] args) {
    if(args == null || args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        return; 
    }

    //How I do this below?
    for(Object objArray : args) { //this one is good.
        if(objArray == null) continue;
            //objArray = (Object[]) objArray; //can't figure this out.
            for(Object eachObject : objArray) { //this don't work.
                System.out.println("eachObject reference = " + eachObject);
            }
    }

    for(Object[] objArray : args) { //this don't work.
        if(objArray == null) continue;
            for(Object eachObject : objArray) { //this don't work.
                System.out.println("eachObject reference = " + eachObject);
            }
    }
}
```

I tried this in Java Console

```
> for(Object[] a : arguments) { System.out.println(a); }
```

Got this error

> Static Error: Bad types in assignment: from Object to Object[]

This looks much worse.

```
Object[][] arguments = {
    { new Object[]{"command", "value"}},  
    { new Object[]{"List_test", Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4")}},
    { new Object[]{"single command"}}
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are declaring the arguements as `OBJect[]` so the compiler knows the `arguements` has some `Object` as elements. But it doesn't know if the element `objects` are again `Object  arrays` or not. So you are not allowed to do these.

But if you are sure that the elements will be only `Object arrays` you can cast to `Object[]` like following

```
            for(Object objArray : args) { 
                if(objArray == null) continue;
                    Object[] ob = (Object[])objArray ;
                    for(Object eachObject : ob) { 
                        System.out.println("eachObject reference = " + eachObject);
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is declared as

```
Object[] arguments ...
```

In other words, it's an array of `Object`. Regardless of what the elements are inside it, the compiler can only guarantee that each element is at least an `Object`.

That's why you can do

```
for(Object objArray : args) { //this one is good.
```

but not

```
for(Object[] objArray : args) { //this don't work.
```

since the `Object[]` referenced by `args` might contain something that isn't an `Object[]`.

For example, you might have had

```
Object[] arguments = {
    new Object[] {"command", "value"},  
    new Object[] {"List_test", Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4")},
    new Object[] {"single command"},
    new Foo(),
    new Bar()
};
```

The compiler can't know what will be in the `Object[]` at run time.

Comment: How do I make it trust me? since I know it's only going to be `Object[]`'s doesn't it use something like `instanceof` to figure out if it's wrong?

Comment: @SSpoke Declare your variable as an `Object[][]` and instantiate it accordingly. No, you can't force the enhanced for loop to use `instanceof`.

Comment: @SSpoke In this case, probably. But that might not be appropriate elsewhere. Consider some sort of encapsulation for your objects.

Comment: Haha I just got over-excited there is no reason to actually use `Object[][]`  the solutions StinePike and Keppil posted work wonderfully. Just tested.. the `Object[][]` solution would just make the loop look better but the arguments will have lots of extra brackets in them. Ya... I don't want to create a class for the arguments better like this could be anything.. that's how i like it.

Comment: @SSpoke Note that using `Object[][]` is type safe. But if you are _sure_ about what's in the `Object[]`, those solutions are fine. Again, I can't stress this enough, I don't recommend this. Write your own types and use those.

Answer (score 1):

You cant change an existing variable and give it a new type. You can however cast it and assign it to a new variable of the type you want:

```
for(Object obj : args) { //this one is good.
    if (obj == null) continue;
    Object[] objArray = (Object[]) obj; //Assigning to new variable instead
    for(Object eachObject : objArray) { //Now this works!
        System.out.println("eachObject reference = " + eachObject);
    }
}
```